# Distributed training using MirrorStrategy in tensorflow 2.2 with custom training loop not working - getting stuck when updating gradients

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, parallel-processing, tensorflow2.0

I'm using tf.distribute.Strategy to train a model, based on unet, with MirrorStrategy over two (or more) gpus. Below is my code for the custom train loop I use for the forward and backward passes of the network. For some reason, the logits, loss and gradients of the first batch of the first epoch are calculated but then it gets stuck at optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables). I can't for the life of me what the problem is so any help would be much appreciated.

```
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Progbar
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Activation, Dense, BatchNormalization, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import UpSampling2D, concatenate
from evaluation import diceCoef

tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)


class Train():
    def __init__(self, model, lossFunc, optimizer, strategy, epochs, batchSize):
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.batchSize = batchSize
        self.strategy = strategy
        #self.lossFunc = lossFunc
        self.lossFunc = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True, reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE)
        self.optimizer = optimizer
        self.model = model
        self.history = {'trainloss': [], 'trainmetric':[], 'valmetric': []}


    def computeLoss(self, yPred, yTrue):

        #loss = tf.reduce_sum(self.lossFunc(yPred, yTrue)) * (1./self.batchSize)
        loss = self.lossFunc(yPred, yTrue)
        loss = loss * (1. / self.strategy.num_replicas_in_sync)
        #print(loss)

        return loss


    @tf.function
    def trainStep(self, x, y, i):
        #x = batch[0]
        #y = batch[1]
        x = tf.cast(x, tf.float32)
        y = tf.cast(y, tf.float32) 
        #print(self.model.trainable_variables)
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            logits = self.model(x, training=True)
            logits = tf.cast(logits, tf.float32) 
            loss = self.computeLoss(logits, y)
            #loss = self.lossFunc(logits, y)
            #print('loss', loss)
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.model.trainable_variables)
        print(len(gradients))
        print(len(self.model.trainable_variables))
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.model.trainable_variables))
        return loss, logits


    @tf.function
    def validStep(self, x, y):
        logits = self.model(x, training=False)
        loss = self.lossFunc(y, logits)

        return loss, logits,


    @tf.function
    def distributedTrainEpoch(self, dataset, trainSteps):

        totalDice = 0
        totalLoss = 0
        #prog = Progbar(trainSteps-1)

        for i, batch in enumerate(dataset):
            x = batch[0]
            #y = tf.expand_dims(batch[1], axis=-1)
            y = batch[1]
            batchLoss, logits = self.strategy.run(self.trainStep, args=(x,y,i))
            print('batchloss', batchLoss)
            #pred = (logits.numpy() > 0.5).astype('int16').astype(np.float16)
            #batchDice = self.strategy.run(diceCoef, args=(pred, y))
            totalLoss += self.strategy.reduce(tf.distribute.ReduceOp.SUM, batchLoss, axis=None)
            #totalDice += self.strategy.reduce(tf.distribute.ReduceOp.SUM, batchDice, axis=None)
            #prog.update(i)

        return totalLoss, totalDice


    @tf.function
    def distributedValidEpoch(self, dataset):
        totalLoss = 0
        totalDice = 0
        for d in dataset:
            x = d[0]
            y = tf.expand_dims(d[1], axis=-1)
            loss, logits = self.strategy.run(self.validStep, args=(x, y))
            pred = (logits.numpy() > 0.5).astype('int16').astype(np.float16)
            dice = self.strategy.run(diceCoef, args=(pred, y))
            totalLoss += self.strategy.reduce(tf.distribute.ReduceOp.SUM, loss, axis=None)
            totalDice += self.strategy.reduce(tf.distribute.ReduceOp.SUM, dice, axis=None)

        return totalLoss, totalDice


    def forward(self, trainDataset, validDataset, trainSteps, validSteps):

        for e in range(self.epochs):

            tf.print('Epoch: {}/{}...'.format(e+1, self.epochs), end="")

            trainLoss, trainDice = self.distributedTrainEpoch(trainDataset, trainSteps)
            avgTrainDice = trainDice.numpy()[0] / trainSteps
            avgTrainLoss = trainLoss.numpy() / trainSteps
            print('train', avgTrainDice)
            print('loss', avgTrainLoss)

            tf.print(' Epoch: {}/{},  loss - {:.2f}, dice - {:.2f}'.format(e+1,
                   self.epochs, avgTrainLoss, avgTrainDice), end="")

            valLoss, valDice = self.distributedValidEpoch(validDataset)

            avgValidDice = valDice.numpy()[0] / validSteps
            avgValidLoss = valLoss.numpy() / validSteps


            self.history['trainmetric'].append(avgTrainDice)
            self.history['trainloss'].append(avgTrainLoss)
            self.history['valmetric'].append(avgValidDice)
            self.history['valmetric'].append(avgValidLoss)

            tf.print('  val_loss - {:.3f}, val_dice - {:.3f}'.format(avgValidLoss, avgValidDice))

        return self.model, history
```

This is the part of the code from another script that sets up the strategy scope, builds the model and calls the train class.

```
 with strategy.scope():

        if model == 'fcn8':
            print('Model: {}'.format(model))
            with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
                if api == 'functional':
                    fcn = FCN()
                    model = fcn.getFCN8()
                elif api=='subclass':
                    model = FCN()

        elif model == 'unet':
            print('Model: {}'.format(model))
            with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
                if api=='functional':
                    unetModel = unet2.UnetFunc()
                    model = unetModel.unet()
                elif api=='subclass':
                    model = unetsc.UnetSC(filters=filters)
                    model.build((1, imgDims, imgDims, 3))

        elif model == 'unetmini':
            print('Model: {}'.format(model))
            with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
                if api == 'functional':
                    unetminiModel = UnetMini(filters=filters)
                    model = unetminiModel.unetmini()
                elif api=='subclass':
                    model = UnetMini(filters)

        elif model == 'resunet':
            print('Model: {}'.format(model))
            with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
                if api=='functional':
                    resunetModel =  ResUnet(filters)
                    model = resunetModel.ResUnetFunc()
                elif api=='subclass':
                    model = ResunetSc(filters)

        elif model == 'resunet-a':
            print('Model: {}'.format(model))
            with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
                if api=='functional':
                    resunetModel =  ResUnetA(filters)
                    model = resunetModel.ResUnetAFunc()
                elif api=='subclass':
                    model = ResunetASc(filters)

        elif model == 'attention':
            print('Model: {}'.format(model))
            with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
                if api == 'functional':
                    attenModel = AttenUnetFunc(filters)
                    model = attenModel.attenUnet()
                elif api=='subclass':
                    model = AttenUnetSC(filters)
        else:
            raise ValueError('No model requested, please update config file')

#        print('trainable variables', str(model.trainable_variables))

        trainer = train.Train(model, loss, optimizer, strategy, epoch, batchSize)

        trainDistDataset = strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset(trainDataset)
        validDistDataset = strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset(validDataset)

        model, history = trainer.forward(trainDistDataset, validDistDataset, trainSteps, validSteps)
```

And the subclassed unet model as follows:

```
class UnetSC(Model):
    def __init__(self, filters=[16,32,64,128, 256], finalActivation='sigmoid', activation='relu', 
                    nOutput=1, kSize=(3,3), pSize=(2,2), dropout=0, normalize=True, padding='same', dtype='float32'):
        super(UnetSC, self).__init__(dtype=dtype)

        self.normalize = normalize
        self.conve1_1 = Conv2D(filters[0], kSize, activation='relu', padding='same', name='greg')
        self.batchnorm1 = BatchNormalization(name='greggggggg')
        self.conve1_2 = Conv2D(filters[0], kSize, activation='relu', padding='same')
        self.batchnorm2 = BatchNormalization()
        self.pool1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))

        self.conve2_1 = Conv2D(filters[1], kSize, activation='relu', padding='same')
        self.batchnorm3 = BatchNormalization()
        self.conve2_2 = Conv2D(filters[1], kSize, activation='relu', padding='same')
        self.batchnorm4 = BatchNormalization()
        self.pool2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))

        self.conve3_1 = Conv2D(filters[2], kSize, activation='relu', padding='same')
        self.batchnorm5 = BatchNormalization()
        self.conve3_2 = Conv2D(filters[2], kSize, activation='relu', padding='same')
        self.batchnorm6 = BatchNormalization()
        self.pool3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))

        self.conve4_1 = Conv2D(filters[3], kSize, activation='relu', padding='same')
        self.batchnorm7 = BatchNormalization()
        self.conve4_2 = Conv2D(filters[3], kSize, activation='relu', padding='same', name='finalencoder')
        self.batchnorm8 = BatchNormalization()
        self.pool4 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))

        self.convb_1 = Conv2D(filters[4], kSize, activation='relu', padding='same')
        self.batchnorm9 = BatchNormalization()
        self.convb_2 = Conv2D(filters[4], kSize, activation='relu', padding='same')
        self.batchnorm10 = BatchNormalization()

        self.upsampling1 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))
        self.conc1 = Concatenate()
        self.convd1_1 = Conv2D(filters[3], kSize, activation='relu', padding='same')
        self.batchnorm11 = BatchNormalization()
        self.convd1_2 = Conv2D(filters[3], kSize, activation='relu', padding='same')
        self.batchnorm12 = BatchNormalization()

        self.upsampling2 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))
        self.conc2 = Concatenate()
        self.convd2_1 = Conv2D(filters[2], kSize, activation='relu', padding='same')
        self.batchnorm13 = BatchNormalization()
        self.convd2_2 = Conv2D(filters[2], kSize, activation='relu', padding='same')
        self.batchnorm14 = BatchNormalization()

        self.upsampling3 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))
        self.conc3 = Concatenate()
        self.convd3_1 = Conv2D(filters[1], kSize, activation='relu', padding='same')
        self.batchnorm15 = BatchNormalization()
        self.convd3_2 = Conv2D(filters[1], kSize, activation='relu', padding='same')
        self.batchnorm16 = BatchNormalization()

        self.upsampling4 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))
        self.conc4 = Concatenate()
        self.convd4_1 = Conv2D(filters[0], kSize, activation='relu', padding='same')
        self.batchnorm17 = BatchNormalization()
        self.convd4_2 = Conv2D(filters[0], kSize, activation='relu', padding='same')
        self.batchnorm18 = BatchNormalization()

        self.final = Conv2D(nOutput, kernel_size=(1, 1), strides=(1, 1), activation=finalActivation)


    def call(self, x, training=True):

        e1 = self.conve1_1(x)
        e1 = self.batchnorm1(e1)
        e1 = self.conve1_2(e1)
        e1 = self.batchnorm2(e1)
        p1 = self.pool1(e1)

        e2 = self.conve2_1(p1)
        e2 = self.batchnorm3(e2)
        e2 = self.conve2_2(e2)
        e2 = self.batchnorm4(e2)
        p2 = self.pool2(e2)

        e3 = self.conve3_1(p2)
        e3 = self.batchnorm5(e3)
        e3 = self.conve3_2(e3)
        e3 = self.batchnorm6(e3)
        p3 = self.pool3(e3)

        e4 = self.conve4_1(p3)
        e4 = self.batchnorm7(e4)
        e4 = self.conve4_2(e4)
        e4 = self.batchnorm8(e4)
        p4 = self.pool4(e4)

        b = self.convb_1(p4)
        b = self.batchnorm9(b)
        b = self.convb_2(b)
        b = self.batchnorm10(b)

        d1 = self.upsampling1(b)
        d1 = self.conc1([e4, d1])
        d1 = self.convd1_1(d1)
        d1 = self.batchnorm11(d1)
        d1 = self.convd1_2(d1)
        d1 = self.batchnorm12(d1)

        d2 = self.upsampling2(d1)
        d2 = self.conc2([e3, d2])
        d2 = self.convd2_1(d2)
        d2 = self.batchnorm13(d2)
        d2 = self.convd2_2(d2)
        d2 = self.batchnorm14(d2)

        d3 = self.upsampling3(d2)
        d3 = self.conc3([e2, d3])
        d3 = self.convd3_1(d3)
        d3 = self.batchnorm15(d3)
        d3 = self.convd3_2(d3)
        d3 = self.batchnorm16(d3)

        d4 = self.upsampling4(d3)
        d4 = self.conc4([e1, d4])
        d4 = self.convd4_1(d4)
        d4 = self.batchnorm17(d4)
        d4 = self.convd4_2(d4)
        d4 = self.batchnorm18(d4)

        x = self.final(d4)

        return x


u = UnetSC()
u = u.build((1, 256,256,3))

The error output trace 

Using TensorFlow backend.

Now executing following model: unet_32_adam_diceloss_FR_0_2.5x_germ_32
2020-06-12 18:14:00.672680: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-06-12 18:14:00.815119: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:3f:00.0 name: Tesla V100-PCIE-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.38GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.75GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2020-06-12 18:14:00.816539: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 1 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:40:00.0 name: Tesla V100-PCIE-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.38GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.75GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2020-06-12 18:14:00.817342: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-06-12 18:14:00.820640: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-06-12 18:14:00.823040: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-06-12 18:14:00.823833: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-06-12 18:14:00.826794: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-06-12 18:14:00.829026: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-06-12 18:14:00.834643: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-06-12 18:14:00.839962: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1
2020-06-12 18:14:00.840532: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 AVX512F FMA
2020-06-12 18:14:00.855173: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:102] CPU Frequency: 2200000000 Hz
2020-06-12 18:14:00.857769: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x58fdc10 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-06-12 18:14:00.857804: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-06-12 18:14:01.277928: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x59680f0 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-06-12 18:14:01.278008: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Tesla V100-PCIE-16GB, Compute Capability 7.0
2020-06-12 18:14:01.278031: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (1): Tesla V100-PCIE-16GB, Compute Capability 7.0
2020-06-12 18:14:01.284602: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:3f:00.0 name: Tesla V100-PCIE-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.38GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.75GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2020-06-12 18:14:01.291638: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 1 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:40:00.0 name: Tesla V100-PCIE-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.38GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.75GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2020-06-12 18:14:01.291808: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-06-12 18:14:01.291883: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-06-12 18:14:01.291935: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-06-12 18:14:01.291988: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-06-12 18:14:01.292039: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-06-12 18:14:01.292086: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-06-12 18:14:01.292151: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-06-12 18:14:01.304148: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1
2020-06-12 18:14:01.304295: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-06-12 18:14:01.312107: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-06-12 18:14:01.312143: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1108]      0 1 
2020-06-12 18:14:01.312164: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 0:   N Y 
2020-06-12 18:14:01.312180: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 1:   Y N 
2020-06-12 18:14:01.318105: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1247] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 14864 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla V100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:3f:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
2020-06-12 18:14:01.320434: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1247] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 14864 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: Tesla V100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:40:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)

Epoch: 1/40...WARNING:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy eagerly has significant overhead currently. We will be working on improving this in the future, but for now please wrap `call_for_each_replica` or `experimental_run` or `run` inside a tf.function to get the best performance.
2020-06-12 18:14:16.135798: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-06-12 18:14:18.493751: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10


74
74

74
74
```

Then it just sticks here. Please help!

Comment: From experience, I would not be surprised if the error was related to iterating through the dataset in a wrong way. Like trying/attempting to iterate through it batch by batch or example by example, while actually iterating through it "x" (=train data) by "y" (=labels), trying to feed all training data through the network at once. That's at least an unfortunate error I have faced in the past, which took some time to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I would have left this as a comment, but don't have enough reputation. Have you tried without all those `@tf.function` decorators, is it the same? And if the problem is in the `trainStep` function, maybe you could try variants, I think that possibly you need to have trainable_variables passed as an argument to that function.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this myself, here is the whole code snippet to train my network which uses a mirror strategy to run the training on multiple gpus. This calculates the per replica loss and dice score for each gpu and sums them accordingly. Note in the compute loss, the correct way to calculate the loss over all pixels and divide by the total dimensions to get the average loss per image (we get a loss value for each pixel).

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import datetime
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Progbar
from custom_loss_classes import WeightedBinaryCrossEntropy
from evaluation import diceCoef

#import memory_saving_gradients
#tf.__dict__["gradients"] = memory_saving_gradients.gradients_speed


class DistributeTrain():

    def __init__(self, epochs, model, optimizer, lossObject, batchSize,
                 strategy, trainSteps, testNum, imgDims, threshold, modelName, currentTime, currentDate):
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.batchSize = batchSize
        self.strategy = strategy
        self.loss_object = lossObject
        self.optimizer = optimizer
        self.metric = diceCoef
        self.model = model
        self.trainSteps = trainSteps
        self.testNum = testNum
        self.imgDims = imgDims
        self.history = {'trainloss': [], 'trainmetric':[], 'valmetric': [],'valloss':[]}
        self.threshold = threshold
        self.modelName = modelName
        self.currentTime = currentTime
        self.currentDate = currentDate

    def computeLoss(self, label, predictions):
        
        loss = self.loss_object(label, predictions)
        print('loss', loss)

        loss = tf.reduce_sum(loss) * (1. / (self.imgDims*self.imgDims*self.batchSize))

        return loss * (1/self.strategy.num_replicas_in_sync)


    def computeDice(self, yTrue, yPred):

        dice = self.metric(yTrue, yPred)
        dice = dice * (1 / self.strategy.num_replicas_in_sync)

        return dice


    def trainStep(self, inputs):

        x, y = inputs

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

            logits = self.model(x, training=True)
            loss = self.computeLoss(y, logits)

            yPred = tf.cast((logits > 0.5), tf.float32)
            dice = self.computeDice(y, yPred)

            gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.model.trainable_variables)
            self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.model.trainable_variables))

        return loss, dice


    def testStep(self, inputs):

        x, y = inputs
        predictions = self.model(x, training=False)
        loss = self.loss_object(y, predictions)

        yPred = tf.cast((predictions > 0.5), tf.float32)

    #print('y',np.unique(y.numpy()))
    #print('yPred', np.unique(yPred.numpy()))

        dice = self.computeDice(y, yPred)
        loss = tf.reduce_sum(loss) * (1. / (self.imgDims*self.imgDims*self.batchSize))

        return loss, dice


    @tf.function
    def distributedTrainEpoch(self, batch):

      #totalLoss = 0.0
      #totalDice = 0.0
      #i = 0
      #prog = Progbar(self.trainSteps-1)
      #for batch in trainData:
          #i+=1
        replicaLoss, replicaDice = self.strategy.run(self.trainStep, args=(batch,))
         # totalLoss += self.strategy.reduce(tf.distribute.ReduceOp.SUM, replicaLoss, axis=None)
         # totalDice += self.strategy.reduce(tf.distribute.ReduceOp.SUM, replicaDice, axis=None)
          #prog.update(i)
      #return totalLoss, totalDice
        return replicaLoss, replicaDice

    #ToDo: shitty hack to include progbar in distributed train function. need a
    #way of converting tensor i to integer
    def getDistTrainEpoch(self, trainData):

        totalLoss = 0.0
        totalDice = 0.0
        i = 0
        prog = Progbar(self.trainSteps-1)
        for batch in trainData:
            replicaLoss, replicaDice = self.distributedTrainEpoch(batch)
            totalLoss += self.strategy.reduce(tf.distribute.ReduceOp.SUM, replicaLoss, axis=None)
            totalDice += self.strategy.reduce(tf.distribute.ReduceOp.SUM, replicaDice, axis=None)
            prog.update(i) 
            i+=1

        return totalLoss, totalDice

    
       
    @tf.function
    def distributedTestEpoch(self, validData):

        totalLoss = 0.0
        totalDice = 0.0

        for d in validData:
            loss, dice = self.strategy.run(self.testStep, args=(d,))
            totalLoss += self.strategy.reduce(tf.distribute.ReduceOp.SUM, loss, axis=None)
            totalDice += self.strategy.reduce(tf.distribute.ReduceOp.SUM, dice, axis=None)

        return totalLoss, totalDice


    #we wantt o stop on a moving average value, min threshold dice and min epoch iterations 
    def earlyStop(self, valDice, epoch):

        ma = np.mean(np.array(self.history['valmetric'][-5:]))
        #removed moving average
        stop = True if epoch > self.threshold['epochs'] and valDice > self.threshold['metric'] else False

        return stop


    def forward(self, trainDistDataset, testDistDataset):

        currentTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')
        trainLogDir = os.path.join('tensorboard_logs', 'train', self.currentDate, self.modelName + '_' + self.currentTime)
        testLogDir = os.path.join('tensorboard_logs', 'test', self.currentDate, self.modelName + '_' + self.currentTime)

        trainWriter = tf.summary.create_file_writer(trainLogDir)
        testWriter = tf.summary.create_file_writer(testLogDir)

        for epoch in range(self.epochs):

            #trainLoss, trainDice = self.distributedTrainEpoch(trainDistDataset)
            trainLoss, trainDice = self.getDistTrainEpoch(trainDistDataset)
            epochTrainLoss, epochTrainDice = float(trainLoss/self.trainSteps), float(trainDice/self.trainSteps)

            with trainWriter.as_default():
                tf.summary.scalar('loss', epochTrainLoss, step=epoch)
                tf.summary.scalar('dice', epochTrainDice, step=epoch)

            tf.print(' Epoch: {}/{},  loss - {:.2f}, dice - {:.2f}, lr - {:.5f}'.format(epoch+1, self.epochs, epochTrainLoss,
                     epochTrainDice, 1), end="")

            testLoss, testDice  =  self.distributedTestEpoch(testDistDataset)
            epochTestLoss, epochTestDice = float(testLoss/self.testNum), float(testDice/self.testNum)

            with testWriter.as_default():
                tf.summary.scalar('loss', epochTestLoss, step=epoch)
                tf.summary.scalar('Dice', epochTestDice, step=epoch)

            tf.print('  val_loss - {:.3f}, val_dice - {:.3f}'.format(epochTestLoss, epochTestDice))

            self.history['trainmetric'].append(epochTrainDice)
            self.history['trainloss'].append(epochTrainLoss)
            self.history['valmetric'].append(epochTestDice)
            self.history['valloss'].append(epochTestLoss)

            if self.earlyStop(epochTestDice, epoch):
                print('Stopping early on epoch: {}'.format(epoch))
                break

        return self.model, self.history
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment out the code that sets eager mode.

```
# tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)
```

I've suffered from the exact same problem. My model with MirroredStrategy worked well with single GPU but got stuck with multiple GPUs at optimizer.apply_gradients(), more specifically, at _merge_call() (infinitely waiting at t.should_run.wait() inside this function).
This had happened when I turned eager mode on with:

```
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
```

After comment out this, my model worked well with multiple GPUs.
This seems to be related to the warning message:

> Epoch: 1/40...WARNING:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy eagerly has
> significant overhead currently. We will be working on improving this
> in the future, but for now please wrap `call_for_each_replica` or
> `experimental_run` or `run` inside a tf.function to get the best
> performance.